# How to POST JSON body into new array?

Tags: javascript, json, post, fetch-api

For the life of me, I can't work this out...

My JSON body looks like this:

> {
> "title": "Example 1",
> "job": "Designer A"
> }

But the API wants it inside an array like:

> [ {
> "title": "Example 1",
> "job": "Designer A"
> } ]

How can I achieve this?.

```
  function handleForm(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); 
    let jobForm = ev.target;
    let fd = new FormData(jobForm);

    //look at all the contents
    for (let key of fd.keys()) {
      console.log(key, fd.get(key));
    }
    let json = convertFD2JSON(fd);

    //send the request with the formdata
    let url = 'HIDDEN_URL';
    let h = new Headers();
    h.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let req = new Request(url, {
      mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
      headers: h,
      body: json,
      method: 'POST',
    });

    fetch(req)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Response from server');
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(console.warn);
  }

  function convertFD2JSON(formData) {
    let obj = {
    };
    for (let key of formData.keys()) {
      obj[key] = formData.get(key);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This one's actually pretty straightforward! We can simply alter the following code:

```
let req = new Request(url, {
  mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
  headers: h,
  body: json,
  method: 'POST',
});
```

To be like this:

```
let req = new Request(url, {
  mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
  headers: h,
  body: [json],
  method: 'POST',
});
```

The difference is in the code above, I encase the JSON variable in [] which defines it as the only element in a new array. This should work exactly how you need it to!

Comment: Thanks for the response.
Sadly that's not working for me.

I get a warning "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input" for this line of the fetch(req)
.then((res) => res.json())

I'm sending the json to a test webhook site which did work, but did not wrap it in [ ]

{
  "job_type": "full-time",
  "job_title": "3D Motion Designer",
  "job_location": "remote",
  "job_level": "senior",
  "salary": "$120K",
  "checkbox": "on",
  "job_description": "<p>this is a nother test</p>",
  "member": "reculfMFCEOTg8fQt"
}

any other ideas?

Comment: This means that the variable json is not actually proper formatted json. I would check that first